# Phpunit getting error messages

Tags: php, unit-testing, phpunit, tdd

Initially my problem was getting an error whenever I add `--coverage-html` in phpunit run. It's weird because I don't get any errors whithout coverage.
The error didn't have any error messages other than the letter `E` in the dots that looked liked this:

```
.....EEEEEEE
```

logs were not telling me on which test the errors where coming from so i read the phpunit doc to find answers and learned that adding `--testdox` would output a checklist format. So I added `--testdox` to my run script. This is what tail of the logs look like:

```
someTestA
 [x] Some test 1
 [ ] Some test 2
 [ ] Some test 3

someTestB
```

It literally wasn't spitting out any logs after the line `someTestB`. I am now on quest to get error messages on my why those tests are failing.

This is my run script:

```
$ phpunit --configuration phpunit-configs/myconfig.xml --testdox --coverage-html test-reports/html
```

This is what my phpunit config looks like:

```
<phpunit
    backupGlobals="false"
    backupStaticAttributes="false"
    bootstrap="../tests/bootstrap.php"
    colors="true"
    convertErrorsToExceptions="false"
    convertNoticesToExceptions="false"
    convertWarningsToExceptions="false"
    processIsolation="false"
    stopOnFailure="false"
    syntaxCheck="false"
    verbose="true"
>
```

This is what my php ini looks like:

```
<php>
    <server name="REQUEST_METHOD" value="GET" />
    <server name="REMOTE_ADDR" value="127.0.0.1" />
    <server name="SERVER_SOFTWARE" value="PHP CLI" />
    <ini name="memory_limit" value="2048M" />
    <ini name="error_reporting" value="E_ALL" />
    <ini name="display_errors" value="On" />
    <ini name="display_startup_errors" value="On" />
</php>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your version of PHPUnit is outdated. Recent version print detailed information in case a test is not successfully executed when TestDox output is  used.

Comment: Where can I tail the logs atleast?. Upgrading phpunit is not option at the moment

Comment: After tailing the logs i still am not able to get any information

Comment: Do not use `--testdox` if you do not want TestDox output.